# Sci-fi book about pollution causing mutated sea life including mutated giant squid

Tags: story-identification, mutant

Many years ago, I read a rather thin sci-fi book about some scientists finding mutated sea life caused by pollution coming from cylinders dumped at sea by some bad guys.  This included a couple of mutated giant squid like creatures who had eggs in an underwater cave.  The scientists ended up blowing up the cave and killing one squid to stop the eggs hatching, and the other squid washed up on the beach.  This monster on the beach ended up killing some of the bad guys as they were running along the beach.

The cover had a picture of one of the giant squid like creatures with its tentacles flowing around the place, and for years I had the thought it was called "Deep Six" but I have had no luck whatsoever in finding the book.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds a bit like Mutant beach (Tom Swift) by Victor Appleton, II though the "pollution" is genetic manipulation, not radiation or chemical.

While Tom is working on a scientific experiment with growth hormones to create larger fish and help feed starving people around the world, someone else at Laguna Pequeña beach is producing a genetic nightmare of giant squid and shark, and poisonous fish.  They may want to experiment on people next!

[Mutant Beach Cover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671756575)

Comment: Thanks for the help biechst...that might not be the book I'm after, but it DOES sound very interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

your description remind me of The swarm by Frank Schätzing , probably non related, but did remind me of.

Comment: Could you expand a little, what parts of that story match up with what the OP described?